# Elegant way to make all dirs in a path

Tags: python, path

Here are four paths:

```
p1=r'\foo\bar\foobar.txt'
p2=r'\foo\bar\foo\foo\foobar.txt'
p3=r'\foo\bar\foo\foo2\foobar.txt'
p4=r'\foo2\bar\foo\foo\foobar.txt'
```

The directories may or may not exist on a drive. What would be the most elegant way to create the directories in each path?

I was thinking about using `os.path.split()` in a loop, and checking for a dir with `os.path.exists`, but I don't know it there's a better approach.

Comment: Almost: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6004073/1959808

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You are looking for [`os.makedirs()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) which does exactly what you need.

The documentation states:

> Recursive directory creation function.
> Like mkdir(), but makes all
> intermediate-level directories needed
> to contain the leaf directory. Raises
> an error exception if the leaf
> directory already exists or cannot be
> created.

By default it fails if the leaf directory already exists; you'll want to test for existence before calling `os.makedirs()` or use `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)` to ignore existence.

Comment: Lol. 1:0 for Python. Can't believe I've missed that and that I've been using `os.mkdir()` exclusively. Thanks, David :)

Comment: @marw I'd never heard of it either, I just did a websearch with the magic key word "recursive"!

Comment: testing on existence introduces possible race condition (the directory might be created *after* you tested its existance by *before* your call to `makedirs()`). So just use `try: .. except OSError` without the test.

Comment: @J.F. Well, that doesn't really help much because the operation to make the directories is not atomic anyway. Race issues are unavoidable unless you have a proper transactional filesystem.

Comment: @David Heffernan: You're right it won't solve all problems e.g., world hunger. One step at a time. btw, if you don't like `try: except`; use `exist_ok=True`.

Comment: @J.F. exist_ok is neat, I didn't see it since it seems to be very new - I was looking at 2.7 docs. Thanks!

Comment: @jfs Nice! I wish your comment were highlighted in the answer because I missed it a few times ago when I looked at this topic.

Comment: *equivalent of* `mkdir -p`

Answer (score 58):

On Python 3.6+ you can do:

```
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path(p4)
path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: The pathlib module needs a publicity campaign. It is awesome.

Comment: @RickTeachey couldn't agree more

Comment: I love it too. Here with only one line: 
`pathlib.Path("/path/with/dirs").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to build the paths in POSIX systems.  Assume your path is something like: `dirPath = '../foo/bar'`, where neither `foo` or `bar` exist:

```
path = ''
for d in dirPath.split('/'):
   # handle instances of // in string
   if not d: continue 

   path += d + '/'
   if not os.path.isdir(path):
      os.mkdir(path)
```