# How can I create directories recursively?

Tags: python

Is there a Python method to create directories recursively? I have this path:

```
/home/dail/
```

I would like to create

```
/home/dail/first/second/third
```

Can I do it recursively or I have to create one directory after the other?

The same thing for:

**chmod** and **chown** can I do it recursively without assign permissions for each file/dir?

Comment: superset: also check if exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600268/mkdir-p-functionality-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I safely create a nested directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273192/608639)

Comment: @CiroSantilli冠状病毒审查六四事件法轮功 Thanks, very useful. btw, I like you name and portrait, bro!

Comment: @Chen thanks! It's fun right? :-)

Answer (score 414):

starting from python 3.2 you can do this:

```
import os
path = '/home/dail/first/second/third'
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
```

thanks to the [`exist_ok` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) this will not even complain if the directory exists (depending on your needs....).

---

starting from python 3.4 (which includes the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)) you can do this:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('/home/dail/first/second/third')
path.mkdir(parents=True)
```

---

starting from python 3.5 [`mkdir` also has an `exist_ok` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) - setting it to `True` will raise no exception if the directory exists:

```
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I always was using os.mkdir which didn't make grandchildren and more nested children. os.makedirs just solved my problem

Comment: @Hamed_gibago you do not even need to use the `pathlib` module. [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) is recursive itself...

Comment: Nice one. `pathlib` works for me.

Answer (score 258):

[`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) is what you need. For `chmod` or `chown` you'll have to use `os.walk` and use it on every file/dir yourself.

Comment: Specifically: os.makedirs(os.path.join("/home/dail", "first", "second", "third"))

Comment: note, `exist_ok=True` is convenient to save having to check if it exists first every time.

Comment: Note that the `exist_ok` parameter was only added in Python 3.2

Answer (score 15):

Try using [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs):

```
import os
import errno

try:
    os.makedirs(<path>)
except OSError as e:
    if errno.EEXIST != e.errno:
        raise
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I would say this answer is the correct one for Python 2.x, since it handles errors correctly and doesn't asks for file system for path twice (as with `os.path.exists` approach).

Answer (score 8):

Here is my implementation for your reference:

```
def _mkdir_recursive(self, path):
    sub_path = os.path.dirname(path)
    if not os.path.exists(sub_path):
        self._mkdir_recursive(sub_path)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: If the first folder doesn't exist this function will result in stack overflow (`if not os.path.exists(sub_path)` will always be true and call itself). But as long as the first dir exist this seems to be working.

Comment: Simply resolved by first checking if the first folder exists.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with [Cat Plus Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004084/119775)'s answer.  However, if you know this will only be used on Unix-like OSes, you can use external calls to the shell commands `mkdir`, `chmod`, and `chown`. Make sure to pass extra flags to recursively affect directories:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['mkdir', '-p', 'first/second/third']) 
# Equivalent to running 'mkdir -p first/second/third' in a shell (which creates
# parent directories if they do not yet exist).

>>> subprocess.check_output(['chown', '-R', 'dail:users', 'first'])
# Recursively change owner to 'dail' and group to 'users' for 'first' and all of
# its subdirectories.

>>> subprocess.check_output(['chmod', '-R', 'g+w', 'first'])
# Add group write permissions to 'first' and all of its subdirectories.
```

**EDIT** I originally used `commands`, which was a bad choice since it is deprecated and vulnerable to injection attacks. (For example, if a user gave input to create a directory called `first/;rm -rf --no-preserve-root /;`, one could potentially delete all directories).

**EDIT 2** If you are using Python less than 2.7, use `check_call` instead of `check_output`. See the [`subprocess` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions) for details.

Comment: But that's not Python, it's a shell script! If you can write a solution in Python that's pretty simple, and even portable, do it that way. ;)

Comment: @Rosh: I agree 100% that its python calling the *nix shell commands and isn't portable (and said so).  But I often find myself writing quick python scripts that I'll only use on my own linux boxes.  Calling shell commands may be simpler for those purposes, when you can accomplish what you want with a flag (e.g., -R rather than a `walk` double-for loop--(second loop for files in each `walk`ed dir)).  Sure I could have written them in bash, but I feel python's syntax is convenient (easily defining functions/classes) and having access to all the command line flags is convenient for me.

Comment: @dothebart I agree forking is often a bad idea and will have more overhead.  But the difference is a couple milliseconds (so unless you are creating thousands of directories or on a very resource strapped system -- and then you may want to reconsider python).  Sometimes a familiar shell command that does exactly what you want in one line is more convenient than replicating the functionality in python using python's commands that come with less built-in (e.g., python's `os.chmod` and `os.chown` not having recursive options).  Saying forking is always bad seems like a premature optimization.

Comment: have a look at the pyrrd module and rethink. The solution now lifted up deserves more attention - thats wy I voted it up, and this down.

Comment: I fail to see the significance of `pyrrd` (a convenience wrapper around  a round robin db tool and existing python bindings) to this discussion.  According to its [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyRRD/) page, half of that module is just an object oriented interface to calling a binary with `Popen` (that is "forking" which you said  "is always a bad idea").  (`Now, with PyRRD, there are two additional ways to use RRDTool from Python: an object-oriented interface that wraps system calls (Popen) to the rrdtool binary`).

Comment: Python's subprocess module can be used safely (without `shell=True`) and is quite useful when you are already familiar with the shell commands to do your task, and this is the sort of task you don't mind accomplishing with a shell script (that is where you aren't optimizing for a few milliseconds of difference per command).  I really don't care you downvoted (and its now locked), though I disagree that this was an ["an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) of the sort that should be voted down.

Comment: I should add you should *never* do this anywhere near something that talks to untrusted contexts (Ie web/network/users who arent your employees/software you didnt write/etc).

I've never come across a shell callout or similar construction in a web app I've had to maintain I havent been able to exploit into giving me root access and a shell. *Never* encountered it. Same goes with SQL interpolation. Theres no safe way.