# Python, Django, pickle resource Errno2 No such file or directory:

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, nltk, pickle

I'm currently trying to install a poetry generator on my virtualmachine - running ubunutu. When I run the server, and enter the text, and hit generate, I get the below error:

```
Exception Type:     IOError
Exception Value:    

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'poetry_generator/resources/bigram.pickle'

Exception Location:     /home/lee/Downloads/PoEmo-master/poetry_generator/architecture/experts/generating_experts/collocation_expert.py in train, line 31
```

There is no /resources folder within the poetry_generator, and no bigram.pickles file within it either. It identifies linke 31 of the follow script as the issue:

```
import nltk
import os
import pickle
from pattern import en

from poetry_generator.structures.word import Word
from poetry_generator.architecture.experts.generating_experts.word_generating_expert import WordGeneratingExpert
from poetry_generator.settings import resources_dir


class CollocationExpert(WordGeneratingExpert):
    """Generating most common contexts for words for words"""

    def __init__(self, blackboard):
        super(
            CollocationExpert,
            self).__init__(
            blackboard,
            "Collocation Expert")
        self.word_tag_pairs = []

    def train(self):
        bigram_pickle_file = os.path.join(resources_dir, 'bigram.pickle')
        try:
            with open(bigram_pickle_file,'rb') as f:
                self.word_tag_pairs = pickle.load(f)

        except IOError:
            tagged_words = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words(tagset='universal')
            self.word_tag_pairs = list(nltk.bigrams(tagged_words))
            with open(bigram_pickle_file,'w') as f:
                pickle.dump(self.word_tag_pairs,f)


    '''Finding verbs for noun '''

    def _find_verbs(self, word):
        word_bigrams = [(a[0], b[0]) for a, b in self.word_tag_pairs
                                               if a[0] == word.name and a[1] == 'NOUN' and b[1] == 'VERB'
                                               and en.conjugate(b[0], "inf") not in ('be', 'have')]
        return self.__get_best_collocations(word, word_bigrams)

    '''Finding adjectives for noun'''

    def _find_epithets(self, word):
        word_bigrams = [(b[0], a[0]) for (a, b) in self.word_tag_pairs
                        if b[0] == word.name and b[1] == 'NOUN' and a[1] == 'ADJ']
        epithets = self.__get_best_collocations(word, word_bigrams)
        return epithets

    '''Finding nouns described by adjective'''

    def _find_comparisons(self, adjective):
        word_bigrams = [(a[0], b[0]) for (a, b) in self.word_tag_pairs
                        if a[0] == adjective.name and b[1] == 'NOUN' and a[1] == 'ADJ']
        comparisons = self.__get_best_collocations(adjective, word_bigrams)
        return comparisons

    '''Adding epithets for noun to pool'''

    def _add_epithets(self, word):
        epithets = set([Word(w, "JJ") for w in self._find_epithets(word)])
        if word not in self.blackboard.pool.epithets:
            self.blackboard.pool.epithets[word] = []
        self.blackboard.pool.epithets[word] += list(epithets)
        return epithets

    def _add_verbs(self, word):
        verbs = set([Word(w, "V") for w in self._find_verbs(word)])
        self.blackboard.pool.verbs[word] = list(verbs)
        return verbs

    '''Adding nouns for adjectives to pool'''

    def _add_comparisons(self, adj):

        comparisons = set([Word(w, "N") for w in self._find_comparisons(adj)])
        self.blackboard.pool.comparisons[adj] = comparisons
        return comparisons

    def __get_best_collocations(self, word, word_bigrams, n=20):
        words = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(word_bigrams)[word.name]
        best_bigrams = sorted(words.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v, reverse=False)[:n]

        return dict(best_bigrams).keys()

    def generate_words(self):
        super(CollocationExpert, self).generate_words()
        counter = 0
        for w in self.blackboard.pool.nouns:
            eps = self._add_epithets(w)
            vs = self._add_verbs(w)
            le = len(eps)
            lv = len(vs)
            counter += le + lv
        for adj in self.blackboard.pool.adjectives:
            comps = self._add_comparisons(adj)
            counter += len(comps)
        return counter
```

any ideas? I'm new to python so I'm not really clued up. Thanks!

Comment: "(Not sure why everything below isn't being registered as code - but it is)" => you have to indent text by for spaces for it to be displayed as code. The simplest solution is to select the code part and click the "code" button in the editor's toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs on the third line of the `train` method but you catch that one. However, in the catch you try the exact same thing. Changing the way you open the file will not omit the error. If the file/directory does not exist, you need to create it first.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004073/how-can-i-create-directories-recursively) for recursively creating a directory.

For the creating the file, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist) might be helpful.