# Python os.mkdir gives WinError cannot find path

Tags: python, windows

I have the following code snippet

```py
outdir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "new-recipes", "test")
            
print("Output to:", outdir)
print(" ") 

# If directory doesn't exist, make it 
if not os.path.isdir(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir) 
os.chdir(outdir)
```

when I run it on a Windows machine I get the output

```
Output to: C:\Users\wbehrens\Desktop\Code\conan-3pc\new-recipes\test

[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\wbehrens\\Desktop\\Code\\conan-3pc\\new-recipes\\test'
```

I added an absolute path because I found somewhere that it works better but I still get no luck.

Comment: Probably one of the ancestor directories doesn't exist (`new-recipes` for example).

Comment: @CherryDT you're right, is there something akin to a mkdir -p?

Comment: You can use `os.makedirs(outdir, exist_ok=True)` to get `mkdir -p`-like behavior. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004073/how-can-i-create-directories-recursively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more efficient workaround is using the `pathlib` library, which is a little easier to work with when creating paths. This should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
from pathlib import Path

outdir = Path.cwd() / "new-recipes" / "test"
if Path.exists(outdir) == True:
    print("Directory already exists!")
else:
    outdir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    print("Directory created!")
```

The syntax of `pathlib`'s path function is where `Path.exists(outdir)` returns either `True` or `False`. This in turn allows the `if` statement that follows to utilize the output for its logic. For `outdir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`, `parents=True` means that any missing parents of this path are created as needed for the directory. `exist_ok=True` means that no action will be taken to create the directory if the path already exists.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
outdir = "/test"  # or absolute path, which ever you want

# Try making a directory
try:
    os.makedirs(outdir)
except OSError as e:
    print("Directory already exists!")
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem. Instead, it will falsely print `Directory already exists!` when in fact a parent directory is missing.

Comment: You should have mentioned in your question that you wanted to make the parent directory too. In that case replace mkdir with makedirs.