# create the whole hierarchy of directories if nested

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create a hierarchy of directories, if they do not exist.

For example; imagine the path `/tmp/myfolder/myclients`

If `myfolder` exists, I can just use `os.mkdir` to create `myclients` folder, if it does not exist; but how do I create `myfolder` too, in case it does not exist? Because `os.mkdir` does trigger an error if I try to create myclients inside myfolder, if myfolder does not exist

Should I make a call for each folder that is nested and create folders as I go, or there is a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [os.makedirs()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) instead of `os.mkdir()` which will create all missing directories in the path. As the manual says

> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all
>   intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.

Also [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210790/1207049).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would get from google only the version without the extra `s`

Comment: It's not just the plural but `mkdir` vs `makedirs`. By the way, the latter is just below the former in the reference manual. ;)